# In which file is a specified dataframe's attribution definition, such as columns, located?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, package

`pandas` is a huge library in python.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__path__
['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas']
```

I know the pandas library located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas`.

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick'], 'Age':[20, 21]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.cloumns
Index(['Age', 'Name'], dtype='object')
```

`columns` is an attribution of dataframe, i want to know where is the dataframe's attribution `columns` defination?

```
ls  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas
api     conftest.py  __init__.py  plotting     tests    _version.py
arrays  core         io           __pycache__  tseries
compat  errors       _libs        testing.py   util
```

In which directory and which file in the directory does the `columns` attribution locate?
`df.cloumns.__path__` can't give the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`columns` isn't defined in any single place. It is just an attribute on the DataFrame that points to an instance of another object. In particular, `columns` must be an instance of `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index` or one of its subclasses, which are also defined in submodules of `pandas.core.indexes` but are also mostly accessible from the top-level module (e.g. `pd.RangeIndex`).

I am distinguishing "defined" from two possibly-related ideas:

1. Where the attribute is set. (e.g. the line where they go, `self.columns = ...`).
2. How the DataFrame object uses/interacts with the attribute.

### Where is `Index` defined?

The actual path to the base `Index` class is at:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L177

Likewise, on your local installation it will be at

`[..]/python3.x/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py`.

### Where is it written that `columns` must be an instance of an `Index`?

Since python isn't strongly typed this is kind of hard to prove/enforce. However, `DataFrame` inherits from `NDFrame`, which is its N-dimensional generalization (`Series` is the 1D version). At the end of the day, `NDFrame` stores data in an attribute called... `_data`, which is an instance of `BlockManager`. [Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.0.3/pandas/core/internals/managers.py#L125) you can see that the typings on `axes` (`columns` is a kind of axis) are as an `Index`. All (orthodox) modifications to these axes will be run through a function [`ensure_index`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.0.3/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L5293), which will convert, e.g., lists to proper indices.

## How is the `column` attribute set and retrieved?

(Maybe this was the main question?)

The index object that `columns` refers to lives in `pd.DataFrame._data.axes[0]`. Custom implementations of [`__getattr__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.0.x/pandas/core/generic.py#L5257) and [`__setattr__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.0.x/pandas/core/generic.py#L5276) then ensure that the call to `DataFrame.columns` returns that element.

But let me back up.

The call to the [`_setup_axes`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L8449) class method alters the `DataFrame` class (*not* instance) to have attributes `columns` and `index`.

In particular, `_setup_axes` [sets](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.0.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L333) the `columns` attribute to be an [`AxisProperty`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx#L45) with argument `axis=0`. You could maybe think of `_setup_axes` as a promise that each instance of the `DataFrame` will have labels for two axes and, further, that these axes have names.

So why do calls to `df.columns` return an Index rather than an `AxisProperty`?

A call to `df.columns` will:

1. Enter  [`__getattr__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.0.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L5257).
2. Find `columns` among the entries in `self._internal_names_set` so go to line [5270](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.0.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L5270)
3. [5270] `return object.__getattribute__(self, name)`.
4. Triggers [`__get__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx#L55) method of `AxisProperty`. Notice that the second argument here (`obj`) is our DataFrame instance(!).
5. On [63](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx#L63) access `obj._data.axes`, i.e. the `_data[.axes]` attribute of the dataframe.
6. On [64](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx#L64) return the element of `obj._data.axes` corresponding to `self.axis`. The call to [`_setup_axes`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.0.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L333) had set `self.axis=0` so we get the 0th element.

Setting `df.columns` (after initialization) works in a similar manner. When the DataFrame is initialized the columns are coerced into an `Index` type, added to a list of axes, and passed as an argument to init a `BlockManager`, which is then assigned to the `_data` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(pd.DataFrame)
'/Users/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py'
```

DataFrames would be initialized via `__init__`:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L414

Specifically, when constucting a DataFrame from a dict, it uses the `@classmethod` to instantiate the DF:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L1169

```
@classmethod
def from_dict(cls, data, orient="columns", dtype=None, columns=None) - "DataFrame":
    ...
    return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
```

Checked that file in github and *think* this is where the `columns` attribute is set:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L8449

```
DataFrame._setup_axes(
    ["index", "columns"],
    docs={
        "index": "The index (row labels) of the DataFrame.",
        "columns": "The column labels of the DataFrame.",
    },
)
```

EDIT: Added reference to `def __init__`, `def from_dict` and changed paths to stable pandas version

Comment: never seen inspect library before, that's awesome!

Comment: Contextual help tab in JupyterLab shows this path string for every variable on hover.